# Probability of 50% success chance after 10 trials?

Tags: probability

Sorry this may be a simple question but i can't figure out the answer to this.
If I for example, flip a coin 10 times. **What is the percentage chance of getting just 1 Heads**?

Is it always 50% in the end anyways? Coin tosses are independent events?

Comment: Look up the binomial distribution. The answer in your example would be $10\times 2^{-10}$.

Comment: Really 10×2^−10?

Comment: I'm confused, that seems way too low.

Comment: Why does it seem too low? Does it contradict your intuition, simulation results, ...?

Comment: I just figure, 10 Tails in a row is very rare, so why is 1 heads out of 10 tosses nearly as rare?

Comment: It's 10 times more likely. I wouldn't say that's *nearly* as rare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want one head, then that means you want one head AND 9 tails. So the way that can happen is for example first a head then 9 tails OR first a tail then a head then 8 tails and so on. If you give it a thought, you'll realize there are 10 different ways you can get a head and 9 tails. For each of those ways, the probability of that happening is $$\underbrace{\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \cdots \times \frac{1}{2}}_{\text{10 times}} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10}$$ and since there are **10** ways of this happening we multiply it by 10. $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10} \times 10 \approx 0.00977$$The answer you get however is a decimal answer, so you should multiply that by 100 to get a percentage answer: $0.977\%$